# Excel: How to highlight cells if the neighboring cell value differs by 2 or more?

Tags: excel, if-statement, dataset, compare, conditional-formatting

I have several hundred rows of data in sets of two rows. Each row has ratings from 1-5. I need to highlight the cells when they differ by more than 1. 
For example if one cell has a "4" and the cell below it is "3" or "5" that is ok. If one cell has a "4" but the cell below it has a "1,"2," or "5," both of those cells need to be highlighted. 
I have looked into using conditional formating but this does not help because I can only enter rules asking to highlight < or >, not specific differences of 2 or more. 
Background: The data is two sets of subjective ratings of videos of an autistic patient using psychological measures. If one rater differs from the other rater in scoring by more than "1," the data needs to be highlighted so the scoring for that measure can be discussed. 
The picture is how the data should look like (not actual data file): https://i.stack.imgur.com/78QI1.jpg 
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have two raters and no gaps in Column A after the first video and before the last, please select the range to be formatted starting in C4 and try this CF formula rule:

```
=OR(AND(ISODD(ROW()),ABS(C4-C3)>1),AND(ISEVEN(ROW()),ABS(C4-C5)>1))
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, and because I like to always have the ability to quickly change my conditional formatting, I like to use helper columns.

In this case, you can bring a helper column that you will hide afterwards.

Assuming your data starts in `A2`, and `row 1` is your header rows.  Assuming we are putting a helper column in `B`:

- In `B2` and `B3`:   `=ABS(A2-A3)`
- Drag all the way down

Put cursor in `A1`, conditional formatting based on a formula.

- Formula `=$B1>=2`
- Applies to `$A:$A`

Hide your helper column

[image]

Comment: I'd still bring in a helper colum besides every column.  Not very long to do, and makes modifying the conditional formatting very easy and efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you base your statement about conditional formatting on, because what you describe is entirely possible with conditional formatting.

In conditional formatting you don't have to slavishly click the out of the box cell highlighting rules. You can easily roll your own by using a rule with a formula. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

Select cells A2 to A10, create a new rule that uses a formula and enter this formula:

```
=OR(ABS(A1-A2)>1,ABS(A2-A3)>1)
```

Select a format and apply the rule to more rows/columns as desired.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the first and last number will be most likely highlighted if the cell over/below the range are empty (will count as 0). To avoid that, simply enter text to this cells (a single space will already do).

Comment: @pnuts if the first two values are 5 (starting with A2), then the first 5 will be highlighted if A1 is empty... I simply suggest that this behavior is not wanted... still, the answer isn't wrong, because this only applies to the first and last value... I don't think any of us misunderstood anything here...

Comment: @pnuts sorry but I cant access the picture right now, but do you mean something like `=(MAX(ABS(A1-A2)*(A1<>""),ABS(A3-A2)*(A3<>""))>1)*(A2<>"")`?